# How to remove the submit button on the form included by drupal_get_form?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a `hook_field_widget_form` where I call `drupal_get_form` multiple times.

Here is my code:

```
foreach ($suppliers AS $supplier_id => $supplier) {
    $delivery_information = sbsl_order_delivery_information_new();

    $element['suppliers'][$supplier_id] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $supplier['supplier_information']['visible_name'],
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => TRUE,
    );

    $delivery_information_form = drupal_get_form('sbsl_order_delivery_information_1_form_' . $supplier_id);
    $element['suppliers'][$supplier_id]['delivery_information'] = $delivery_information_form;
  }
```

How can I remove the submit button on the form included by `drupal_get_form`, and only use the submit of `hook_field_widget_form` to submit all the forms included by `drupal_get_form`?

Comment: Can you make the question more specific by adding some code?

Comment: Now i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_render) it will ignore all elements marked as #printed so just add that to the submit button's array.

You'll need to inspect the $delivery_information_form array to see exactly where your button is at, and when you find it you can do something like this:

```
  $delivery_information_form = drupal_get_form('sbsl_order_delivery_information_1_form_' . $supplier_id);
  $delivery_information_form['path']['to']['button']['#printed'] = TRUE;
```

before adding it to the $element array.

Comment: and how might this help him? can you provide a change to his code to solve his problem?

Comment: @tenken I don't know the structure of the form to be embedded, he'd need to drill through the array returned by drupal_get_form to find the buttons in order to add that property.

Comment: When i submit my widget, it seems that the form is only submited once no matter how many times the form is used.

Comment: It seems your basic premise is flawed - you were expecting the submit handler for the embedded form to be invoked multiple times?
I think the correct approach here would be for delivery_information_form to generate the correct number of fieldsets needed using a foreach loop based on the number of suppliers.

Comment: @JesperBayEriksen but I did give you the correct answer to your question (even though the question was based on some flawed assumptions) so accepting the answer would be much appreciated.